# C# WPF program runs in debug but not release without debugging

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wpf

Trying to test a small program in release mode without debugging. Program runs fine in debug mode, and fine in release mode with debugging.  When I try to run in release with no debugging the following happens.

*Note: I've tried multiple configuration modes.  For configurations other than x86 and platform = x86 gives me a mismatch processor architecture error.
Project being built = MSIL  |   Reference architecture of ChilkatDotNet45 is x86

I've run in many different configs.

Is this a project reference being the wrong architecture type or something else?
Do I just need to try to find a different version of MySql.Data.CF library?

Anyways, here's what I have...if you need more request it:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in CWPart2 - WPF.exe

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.CF, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: cwpart2 - wpf.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 547befe6
  Problem Signature 04: CWPart2 - WPF
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 547befe6
  Problem Signature 07: 9f
  Problem Signature 08: ed
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileLoadException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: The error `The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.` generally occurs when your project name has characters that are not valid.  I would start with going to the project properties and removing the spaces and hyphen from the name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a copy of the database files in the Release folder